# How can I reference an exported certificate ARN in Terraform and avoid the 'undeclared resource' error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I’m new to Terraform and can’t figure out why this doesn’t work. I’m trying to reference the certificate ARN (which is exported [per Terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#attributes-reference)), but I keep getting an error that it is undeclared. Anyone know why?

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on cloudfront.tf line 17, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cf_mysite_distribution":
│   17:     acm_certificate_arn = acm_mysite_certificate.arn
│
│ A managed resource "acm_mysite_certificate" "arn" has not been declared in the root module.
```

cf.tf:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cf_mysite_distribution" {
  comment             = "mysite.com CloudFront Distribution"
  enabled             = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = acm_mysite_certificate.arn
    ssl_support_method  = "sni-only"
  }
  ...
}
```

acm.tf

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "acm_mysite_certificate" {
  domain_name       = "mysite.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "acm_mysite_certificate_validation" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.aws_mysite_certificate.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = ["mysite.com", "www.mysite.com"]
}
```

I also tried `depends_on`, but that did not work either. Thank you in advance!

I tried using `depends_on` but that didn't work. I expected the cf.tf file to "wait" for the ACM ARN to exist...

Comment: `aws_acm_certificate.acm_mysite_certificate.arn`. Just as you do in `aws_acm_certificate_validation`.

Comment: Which region is your tf provider set to? And is it a certificate which you have DNS validation domains for already or not?

Comment: The reference should be `resource-type`.`resource-name`.`resource-property`. So `aws_acm_certificate.acm_mysite_certificate.arn`. The code where you are getting the error, you are missing the `resource-type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already the reference in the resource `aws_cloudfront_distribution` is incorrect.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cf_mysite_distribution" {
  comment             = "mysite.com CloudFront Distribution"
  enabled             = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.acm_mysite_certificate.arn ##CHANGE##
    ssl_support_method  = "sni-only"
  }
  ...
}
```

`<RESOURCE TYPE>.<NAME>.<RESOURCE-ATTRIBUTE>` is the format for referencing the attributes for Terraform managed resources.[1].

[[1]](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/references#resources)